# Save page screenshot during scraping using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, screen-scraping, screenshot, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm wondering if there is a way to **save a sreenshot of a page that is being srapped using Simple HTML DOM Parser**. It seems that parser basicly usees **file_get_contents** to get the contetns of a given page.

I don't want to access for the second time, so...

Is it possible to use what is scraped by SHDP to make a screenshot?

It can be echoed in script and it looks smooth, so I guess I could use imagegrabwindow, but it works only on windows machines.

Also I would prefer to avoid using any API's

Comment: If you don't want to use any APIs, then you'll have to build your own HTMl rendering engine. It's like saying "I want to drive a car, but not use a motor, steering wheels, gas pedal, seat, or windshield"

Comment: ok, but there are scripts to render PDFs

Answer (score 0):

To get a screenshot you need a screen.

PHP does not have a screen without a browser.

The browser is on the client side so php has no access to it.

You need some sort of javascript/css to fix the way the page looks.